# Implementing Gamma PDF function

Tags: python, numpy, gamma-distribution

I am trying to implement the Gamma PDF function for the integer argument. First I have implemented it with exponential terms but there were overflows, so I tried to compute the log of it, but the log goes to `-inf` as alpha and beta are increased.
Is there any idea how to implement Gamma PDF from scratch?
Here is my implementation:

```
log_gamma = a * np.log(b) + (a-1) * np.log(lam) - b * lam - np.log(factorial(a-1))
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps but there are a number of implementations at [rosettacode.org](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Gamma_function) you could look at.

Answer (score 1):

This was simply because of calculating factorial of  'a' and then applying the logarithm. Instead, we can calculate logarithm of factorial as sum of logarithms of numbers 1 to a.